# robot_localization: navsat transform node does not publish

Tags: navigation, gps, navsat-transform-node, navsat-transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to tutorial about GPS Integration and use of navsat transform node, i put into node the imu with absolute heading values, odometry that is the output of second instance of EKF and NavSatFix message.

The problem is that the node doesn't publish any data in /odometry/gps. I check the covariances of IMU and odometry message. I check also the value of lat/lon/h of GPS message because I have readed that one of this is NaN the navsat_transform node doesn't make output.

So, what is my fault?

UPDATE 16-03-2016
Bagfile: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1fqLQnQO6oVWszVnM2SWs3OE0/view?usp=sharing

Roslaunch navsat_node: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_1fqLQnQO6oZ0JGUlQwbllqUjA/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE 23-01-2017
Roslaunch navsat_node: https://github.com/NikoGiovannini/nostop_launch_files/blob/c9294d3a64973a4a272f546d417d3989e876d10a/launch/arduino/PC_robot_green_yellow.launch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228531/robot_localization:-navsat-transform-node-does-not-publish/) by [Niko](https://answers.ros.org/users/25510/niko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2016-03-08**:
Please post a sample message for all inputs, as well as your navsat_transform_node configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was in the wrong frame id of the imu message. I corrected it and now the navsat transform work properly.
Begineer mistake.

---

Originally posted by [Niko](https://answers.ros.org/users/25510/niko/) with karma: 33 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) on 2016-06-22**:
Could you explain what you mean by this a little more. I think I am having the same problem.

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-10-04**:
Yes I'd also like to know more about how you fixed this. I am having the same issue.
My Frame ID's are as follows:
IMU: base_link
Encoders: odom
GPS: gps

**Comment by [modotz](https://answers.ros.org/users/29096/modotz/) on 2017-01-23**:
I have the same problem, could you please upload the corrected files?